# FFMpeg Image Capture - continous frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to capture continuous frames from a mpeg video file starting from a specific time stamp. That means assume that I have a video which has total duration of 2 minutes. I need to capture all the frames which are continuous from time 00:01:00. I also want to limit the number of frames capturing to 20. How can I make ffmpeg executable to do this

Thanks
Faisal

Answer (score 5):

As covered in [the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -i input.mpg -frames:v 20 frame_%d.png
```

Will start reading from the input at sixty seconds, and will write 20 video frames to `frame_1.png`, `frame_2.png`, `frame_3.png`, etc.

The note in the docs about the accuracy of `-ss` when used to modify the input file versus the output file if a slower but more accurate timing is necessary.

Comment: I tried it out several times. But I am facing a problem again and again. I am able to capture only one frame. What I meant by that is all the 20 frames I am trying to capture is the same. I am not getting the next frame. I don't know why this happens. Please help me

Comment: @user1537351 Try the more accurate timing by putting `-ss ...` after the input.  Maybe that will help.  Using the latest version of FFmpeg couldn't hurt either.